# invisible part of object

Tags: python, opengl, cube

Ive been on trying to do create some object on opengl and I have trouble with the objects some parts disappearance.

here my code. It is a default exapmle actually but I changed some parts

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QOpenGLWidget, QSlider,
                             QWidget)
import OpenGL.GL as gl

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.glWidget = GLWidget()


        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.glWidget)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Hello GL")

class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    xRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    yRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    zRotationChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.object = 0
        self.xRot = 0
        self.yRot = 0
        self.zRot = 0

        self.lastPos = QPoint()

        self.trolltechGreen = QColor.fromCmykF(0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        self.trolltechPurple = QColor.fromCmykF(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        self.quadric = gluNewQuadric()
    def initializeGL(self):
        print(self.getOpenglInfo())

        self.setClearColor(self.trolltechPurple.darker())
        self.object = self.main()
        gl.glBlendFunc(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND)
        gl.glShadeModel(gl.GL_FLAT)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()


    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(600, 600)

    def setXRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.xRot:
            self.xRot = angle
            self.xRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setYRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.yRot:
            self.yRot = angle
            self.yRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def setZRotation(self, angle):
        angle = self.normalizeAngle(angle)
        if angle != self.zRot:
            self.zRot = angle
            self.zRotationChanged.emit(angle)
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        dx = event.x() - self.lastPos.x()
        dy = event.y() - self.lastPos.y()

        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setYRotation(self.yRot + 8 * dx)
        elif event.buttons() & Qt.RightButton:
            self.setXRotation(self.xRot + 8 * dy)
            self.setZRotation(self.zRot + 8 * dx)

        self.lastPos = event.pos()

    def getOpenglInfo(self):
        info = """
            Vendor: {0}
            Renderer: {1}
            OpenGL Version: {2}
            Shader Version: {3}
        """.format(
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VENDOR),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_RENDERER),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION),
            gl.glGetString(gl.GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)
        )
        return info

    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(
            gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glTranslated(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.xRot / 16.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.yRot / 16.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotated(self.zRot / 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glCallList(self.object)

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        side = min(width, height)
        if side < 0:
            return

        gl.glViewport((width - side) // 2, (height - side) // 2, side,
                           side)

        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        gl.glOrtho(-3, 3, 3, -3, 4.0, 55.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
```

cube and cylinder draft

```
    def main(self):
        genList = gl.glGenLists(1)
        gl.glNewList(genList, gl.GL_COMPILE)

        glPushName(1)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)
        glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  # Allows for light to reflect off certain parts of surface
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glEnd()

        # Back face - Green
        glPushName(2)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5)
        glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glEnd()

        # Left face - Red
        glPushName(3)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5)
        glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glEnd()

        # Right face - Orange
        glPushName(4)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.55, 0.0, 0.5)
        glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glEnd()

        # Top face - White
        glPushName(5)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        glEnd()

        # Bottom face - Yellow
        glPushName(6)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        glEnd()

        # Window on Front (Blue) Face
        glPushName(7)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4)
        glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.25, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.75, 0.25)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.75, 0.75)
        glVertex3f(1.0, 0.25, 0.75)
        glEnd()
        gluCylinder(self.quadric,0.4,0.4,0.3,16,1)
        gl.glEndList()

        return genList
    def setClearColor(self, c):
        gl.glClearColor(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def setColor(self, c):
        gl.glColor4f(c.redF(), c.greenF(), c.blueF(), c.alphaF())

    def normalizeAngle(self, angle):
        while angle < 0:
            angle += 360 * 16
        while angle > 360 * 16:
            angle -= 360 * 16
        return angle

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I have no idea how to solve this problem and I will appreciate for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling). Face culling only works properly if the winding order of all the primitives is the same.

Disable Face Culling:

```py
gl.glDisable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)
```

or simple do not enable it (by default face culling is disabled).

<s>`gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)`</s>

Comment: Face culling is GL_FACE_CULL not GL_DEPTH_TEST! And the questioner's code isn't using it...

Comment: @user253751 1.) Thank you it was a copy/past issue. 2) `gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE)` in `initializeGL()`

Comment: must have mistyped it when I searched

Comment: @user253751 It is not `GL_FACE_CULL` but `GL_CULL_FACE`.

Comment: oh duh. Probably because I was primed with GL_DEPTH_TEST (verb second).